# Piping "svn st" into "svn commit"

Tags: svn

I've got a project that has a config file which I've modified. I want to commit everything I have except the config file. This is the status of svn.

```
?       web/trunk/webroot/tmp
M       web/trunk/webroot/css/styles.css
M       web/trunk/views/posts/list_all.ctp
M       web/trunk/config/core.php
```

And this is the command I run.

```
svn st | grep ? -v | grep config/core.php -v | awk '{print $2;}' | xargs sudo svn commit
```

But I keep getting this message.

```
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: system('/usr/bin/editor svn-commit.tmp') returned 256
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem would be really appreciated.

EDIT: This is kinda interesting. I echoed the result one and this is what I got.

```
svn st | grep ? -v | grep gearman -v | awk '{print $2;}' | xargs echo | awk '{ print "sudo svn commit " $0; }'
```

Output:

```
sudo svn commit web/trunk/webroot/css/backend.css web/trunk/views/store_subscribers/list_all.ctp
```

Running the above result manually works fine but when I piped it into sh,

```
svn st | grep ? -v | grep gearman -v | awk '{print $2;}' | xargs echo | awk '{ print "sudo svn commit " $0; }' | sh
```

Output:

```
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: system('/usr/bin/editor svn-commit.tmp') returned 256
```

Comment: Does SVN give you this error if you do a commit normally?

Comment: @erjiang no, it works fine. I added some more details into the question. Have a look please.

Comment: What happens if you put `&` at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo svn -q commit
```

`-q` is the silent switch and should not force svn to open up the editor to put in a commit message :)

Ideally you should also specify a message via the `-m` switch

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re06.html

Comment: That was a pretty good idea and it worked. Thanks. But the main issue is not fixed yet :( what causes it?

Comment: Basically svn fires up the editor which in your case is `/usr/bin/editor` and you are trying to pipe that into `sh`.

Comment: So, do you reckon changing the editor would fix the issue? or it's gonna happen on any editor, no matter what?

Comment: Yeah changing the editor won't help unfortunately. Unless you somehow manage to pass the editor a default switch to open in silent mode or something. But if you are doing that then you might as well use svn's quiet switch which bypasses the editor =)

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate the convenience of `xargs` with `backticks`

Instead of:

```
svn st | grep ? -v | grep config/core.php -v | awk '{print $2;}' | xargs sudo svn commit
```

You can try:

```
svn ci `svn st | grep ? -v | grep config/core.php -v | awk '{print $2;}'`
```

Just drop the `xargs` command at the end, wrap your query in `backticks`, and add `svn ci` to the front of your example.

Answer (score -2):

Mainly you need to [`svn add`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html) before you `svn commit`. For example, this doesn't work:

```
$ touch testfile
$ svn st
$ svn commit testfile -m 'playing with svn'
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: '/cygdrive/c/web/cpoe_ordersets/testfile' is not under version control
```

But if I remember to `svn add` it it works.

```
$ svn add testfile
A         testfile

$ svn commit testfile -m 'playing with svn'
Adding         testfile
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 1505.
```

So you might want to add an `svn add` command to your pipeline before the commit, or more likely what you really want is to

1. run `svn add * --force` in the root directory to add all unversioned files, then
2. `svn revert config/core.php` which you don't want added
3. run `svn commit -m "I added some unversioned files"` in the root directory to commit all the added files.